# Connecting to Postgres via DBeaver with SSH tunnel

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

Not sure if this should go here, on Superuser, or DBA, let me know.

I'm on Windows 10 using DBeaver 5.1.2, and my Postgres server is on an Ubuntu 18.04 VPS. I'm trying to connect to it with an SSH tunnel, but I can't get it to work. My DB is configured to only allow local connections as the root `postgres` user via the actual `postgres` user account on Ubuntu. I can't figure out how to connect with this though.

I had this set up previously but I had to reinstall DBeaver, so I know it's possible, but I can't figure out how I did it. How can I use an SSH tunnel to connect to Postgres on my Ubuntu server with DBeaver?

Answer (score 2):

### Dbeaver - Database connection using SSH Tunnel

- Open dbeaver
- Click on "**New Database Connection**", in the following "**main**" window enter the PostgreSQL server host relative to the SSH server(here It is MySQL used), and PostgreSQL running port- will be 5432 default, my setting is for MySQL (`localhost`, `3306`)
  specify PostgreSQL user to connect with and user password.
  [image: dbeaver main]
- In the "**SSH**" part, specify the SSH host, port, user also the authentication method used, like SSH private key
  [image: dbeaver ssh]
  Test connection and use.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new connection, during the first step use localhost as the hostname and the credentials you've specified. On the next screen there should be an SSH Tunnel option. That's where you should configure the SSH connection.